# open a HTML page from ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I need to open a seperate html page from a ajax call. I was using the following code. But it is not working.

```
                     $('#cm').blur(function(){
    var cmnumber = document.forms['myform']['cm'].value;

    $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    data:cmnumber,
    success: function(data) {

            if ( data == cmnumber)
            {  alert ("Its a valid CM")}
            else
            { var answer = confirm("Want to create New one")
                if(answer)
                {
                    alert("good")
                    var win=window.open('cm.html',"_self");
                    with(win.document)
                    {
                        open();
                        write();
                        close();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    })
    });
```

I need to open html file "cm.html" on the same page. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: try `self.location = "cm.html"`

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) property:

```
window.location.href = "cm.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're going for with `open()`, `write()`, and `close()`, but you should be able to open the page using [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location):

```
window.location = 'cm.html';
```

Note that you can assign either a relative or fully qualified path.

Comment: Yea its opening now. But i have a retutn value. how i will get it in the mail HTML page which the ajax is calling?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you are asking. Are you trying to load the page contents into a variable?